# Yum problems with easy apache - The server’s system package manager, ‘YUM’, failed.?

Tags: apache-http-server, yum

I keep getting the following error on easy appache

**!! The server’s system package manager, ‘YUM’, failed. !**

I keep getting these errors

I try the following

> yum clean headers
>
> yum clean packages
>
> yum clean metadata
>
> yum clean dbcache
>
> yum clean all

and whe i try

> yum -y update

```
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
httpd-mmn = 20051115 is needed by mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-9.el6_4.x86_64
** Found 3 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
frontpage-2002-SR1.2.i386 has missing requires of libexpat.so.0
mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-2.el6_1.4.x86_64 has missing requires of httpd-mmn = ('0', '20051115', 
None)
sendmail-cf-8.14.4-8.el6.noarch has missing requires of sendmail = ('0', '8.14.4', '8.el6')
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with: yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx
```

When i do a **yum check** i get

```
yum check
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
frontpage-2002-SR1.2.i386 has missing requires of libexpat.so.0
mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-2.el6_1.4.x86_64 has missing requires of httpd-mmn = ('0', '20051115', None)
msttcorefonts-2.5-1.noarch is obsoleted by msttcore-fonts-2.0-3.noarch
sendmail-cf-8.14.4-8.el6.noarch has missing requires of sendmail = ('0', '8.14.4', '8.el6')
Error: check all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some packages requires both 32-bit and 64 bit software to be install

I resolve the issue by

```
yum install libstdc++-devel.i686
```

which seems to be one that was blocking the yum

Answer (score 1):

There are dependencies to software you're trying to install (or have recently tried to install) that `yum` isn't able to resolve due to the software not being found in any repositories you've added.  Specifically, you need

1. [httpd-man](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=httpd-man&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=)
2. [libexpat.so.0](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libexpat.so.0)
3. [sendmail](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=sendmail&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=)

Your best bet is to find a repository for your particular distribution that has these packages and [add it to your yum configuration](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html), for the sake of keeping things up to date.  Of course grabbing the relevant package for your system via the links provided should also give you a quick fix in your current situation.